# Swift. Анимация через StackView

Tags: ios, swift, анимация, uikit

У меня есть StackView, в котором лежат 3 вьюхи (у каждой вьюхи выставлен констрейнт по высоте). Мне нужно по нажатию на кнопку анимировать исчезновение третьей вьюхи и, соответственно, ее появление при повторном нажатии. Проблема заключается в том, что анимация проигрывается, вьюха исчезает, но делает она это некрасиво (проигрывается анимация сжатия StackView, но вьюха до последнего остается изначального размера), и, насколько я понял, это происходит из-за того что у нее задан констрейнт по высоте, т.к. если его убрать, то все отрабатывает хорошо, но сама вьюха с содержимым выглядит некрасиво (внутри нее лейбл и текстфилд, который скукоживается). Как мне решить эту проблему?